# Position two divs right next to each other (responsive) in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a dashboard for appointments and I want it to be this:

[image]

The problem with the code of this picture is that the right box is not responsive. I know why that is (i used `margin:left`), but I don't know how to fix this. Anyone can help me out? Here is my code:

```
<div style="height: 93vh">
  <div class="container-fluid w100 h-100 mt-5">
    <div class="row">
      <nav style="position: fixed;" class="col-md-2 pt-5 sidebar h-100 w100"> ... </nav>
      <div class="col mt-2" style="margin-left: 217px;">
        <main role='main' class='col-md-12 ml-0 ' style='width: 100;background: white;'> ....
```

I have not added classes to the table in `div` yet.

Comment: What do you mean by "responsive"? Stacking to a mobile design? Your question is a bit ambiguous. Also, the `w100` class on your wrapping div (with `container-fluid`) should be `w-100` - assuming you're after that bootstrap class and that's not your own.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this easily with pure CSS and HTML, I used float: left and float:right. The left column is a set width, but the right column's width will be calculated based on the window width.

```css
#toolbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white; /* font color */
}

#left {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 93vh;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
}

#right {
  float: center;
  height: 93vh;
  width: calc(100%-300px);
  background-color: cream;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="toolbar">
  Hello World
</div>
<div id="container">

  <div id="left" >
    menu
  </div>
  
  <div id="right">
   <p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, at ludus praesent cum, ne falli commodo suavitate sea. Augue erant no vim. Sea ex posse blandit mediocritatem. Nec ut laudem audiam qualisque, id sea sale legimus eligendi, iusto persequeris contentiones no sed. Ei prima suscipit mea.

   </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s2103daq/3/

Comment: Ty for you help, unfortunately id did not work with my code. The good news is that I found a solution to my problem. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

A general idea of how we made side `nav` with responsive aside bar, I
use all classes and strut re provide by Bootstrap. No custom code:

```css
.sidebar .dropdown-toggle {
    width: 100%;
}
.sidebar .dropdown-menu {
    width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .sidebar.sidebar-sm .dropdown-toggle {
        display: none;
    }
    .sidebar.sidebar-sm .dropdown-menu {
        border-width: 0px;
        box-shadow: none;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 0;
    }
    .sidebar.sidebar-sm .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 600;
    padding: 15px 10px 10px;
    }
    .sidebar.sidebar-sm .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header:first-child {
        padding-top: 0px;   
    }
    .sidebar.sidebar-sm .dropdown-menu .divider {
        display: none;  
    }
    .sidebar.sidebar-sm .dropdown-menu li a {
        position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    .sidebar.sidebar-sm .dropdown-menu li a:focus, 
    .sidebar.sidebar-sm .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
    color: #555;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }
    .sidebar.sidebar-sm .dropdown-menu li a:focus, 
    .sidebar.sidebar-sm .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
    color: #555;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }
    .sidebar.sidebar-sm .dropdown-menu li.active a, 
    .sidebar.sidebar-sm .dropdown-menu li.active a:focus, 
    .sidebar.sidebar-sm .dropdown-menu li.active a:hover {
    z-index: 2;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #337ab7;
    border-color: #337ab7;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .sidebar.sidebar-md .dropdown-toggle {
        display: none;
    }
    .sidebar.sidebar-md .dropdown-menu {
        border-width: 0px;
        box-shadow: none;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 0;
    }
    .sidebar.sidebar-md .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 600;
    padding: 15px 10px 10px;
    }
    .sidebar.sidebar-md .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header:first-child {
        padding-top: 0px;   
    }
    .sidebar.sidebar-md .dropdown-menu .divider {
        display: none;  
    }
    .sidebar.sidebar-md .dropdown-menu li a {
        position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    .sidebar.sidebar-md .dropdown-menu li a:focus, 
    .sidebar.sidebar-md .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
    color: #555;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }
    .sidebar.sidebar-md .dropdown-menu li a:focus, 
    .sidebar.sidebar-md .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
    color: #555;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }
    .sidebar.sidebar-md .dropdown-menu li.active a, 
    .sidebar.sidebar-md .dropdown-menu li.active a:focus, 
    .sidebar.sidebar-md .dropdown-menu li.active a:hover {
    z-index: 2;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #337ab7;
    border-color: #337ab7;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .sidebar.sidebar-lg .dropdown-toggle {
        display: none;
    }
    .sidebar.sidebar-lg .dropdown-menu {
        border-width: 0px;
        box-shadow: none;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 0;
    }
    .sidebar.sidebar-lg .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 600;
    padding: 15px 10px 10px;
    }
    .sidebar.sidebar-lg .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header:first-child {
        padding-top: 0px;   
    }
    .sidebar.sidebar-lg .dropdown-menu .divider {
        display: none;  
    }
    .sidebar.sidebar-lg .dropdown-menu li a {
        position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    .sidebar.sidebar-lg .dropdown-menu li a:focus, 
    .sidebar.sidebar-lg .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
    color: #555;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }
    .sidebar.sidebar-lg .dropdown-menu li a:focus, 
    .sidebar.sidebar-lg .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
    color: #555;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }
    .sidebar.sidebar-lg .dropdown-menu li.active a, 
    .sidebar.sidebar-lg .dropdown-menu li.active a:focus, 
    .sidebar.sidebar-lg .dropdown-menu li.active a:hover {
    z-index: 2;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #337ab7;
    border-color: #337ab7;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
</header>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="dropdown sidebar sidebar-md">
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                    Dropdown
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Job Type</li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Specialism</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Sample</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <p>Move the needle inclusive improve the world white paper uplift co-create NGO thought provoking strengthening infrastructure. Leverage external partners move the needle energize save the world changemaker shared unit of analysis our work communities. Capacity building save the world shine commitment; deep dive low-hanging fruit innovate, indicators thought leader co-create because disrupt game-changer.</p>

            <p>Energize; energize global, social entrepreneurship social entrepreneur. Outcomes citizen-centered empathetic boots on the ground design thinking thought partnership but leverage co-creation save the world. Mobilize, communities; when movements, scale and impact scale and impact; agile then thought partnership state of play support. Capacity building empower communities, engaging social intrapreneurship, natural resources triple bottom line thought leadership or design thinking.</p>

            <p>Sustainable venture philanthropy; impact design thinking academic, families program area social impact thought partnership justice incubator gender rights milestones. Radical a her body her rights; storytelling our work equal opportunity resilient green space inspiring thought partnership parse. Indicators compelling outcomes entrepreneur, milestones, global low-hanging fruit targeted external partners thought leader overcome injustice challenges and opportunities. Justice radical move the needle scale and impact communities greenwashing. A, silo revolutionary strategize empower communities inspiring shine, improve the world strategize. Leverage; social enterprise, LGBTQ+, incubator shine inspiring parse game-changer systems thinking inclusion.</p>
            <p>Move the needle inclusive improve the world white paper uplift co-create NGO thought provoking strengthening infrastructure. Leverage external partners move the needle energize save the world changemaker shared unit of analysis our work communities. Capacity building save the world shine commitment; deep dive low-hanging fruit innovate, indicators thought leader co-create because disrupt game-changer.</p>

            <p>Energize; energize global, social entrepreneurship social entrepreneur. Outcomes citizen-centered empathetic boots on the ground design thinking thought partnership but leverage co-creation save the world. Mobilize, communities; when movements, scale and impact scale and impact; agile then thought partnership state of play support. Capacity building empower communities, engaging social intrapreneurship, natural resources triple bottom line thought leadership or design thinking.</p>

            <p>Sustainable venture philanthropy; impact design thinking academic, families program area social impact thought partnership justice incubator gender rights milestones. Radical a her body her rights; storytelling our work equal opportunity resilient green space inspiring thought partnership parse. Indicators compelling outcomes entrepreneur, milestones, global low-hanging fruit targeted external partners thought leader overcome injustice challenges and opportunities. Justice radical move the needle scale and impact communities greenwashing. A, silo revolutionary strategize empower communities inspiring shine, improve the world strategize. Leverage; social enterprise, LGBTQ+, incubator shine inspiring parse game-changer systems thinking inclusion.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```